# Two versions of libboost?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, boost, dependencies, libboost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen that running two versions of libboost will cause problems, but I can't figure out how to upgrade my libboost so that I can use an external library.

I'm using the [vicon_bridge](https://github.com/ethz-asl/vicon_bridge) package, which uses a Vicon SDK that seems to need libboost1.53. My `BOOST_LIB_VERSION` macro prints out as `Boost version: 1_46_1`, and `apt-cache policy libboost-dev` returns:

```
libboost-dev:
  Installed: 1.48.0.2
  Candidate: 1.48.0.2
  Version table:
 *** 1.48.0.2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I'm running a 32-bit VM of Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS Hydro. If I run `sudo apt-get install libboost1.54-dev`, apt-get will uninstall all my ros binaries (presumably because they need a 1.4* version of boost).

How can I meet both 1.53 and 1.48 boost version dependencies simultaneously?

EDIT:
I'd assumed that it's a boost library issue, but might not be. Here's the backtrace from the segfault:

```
#0  0xb7aa5108 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0xb7aa6674 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0xb7aa8e4c in malloc () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0xb7ccf627 in operator new(unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0xb7e1117a in ros::PollManager::addPollThreadListener(boost::function<void ()> const&) () from /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so
#5  0xb7e558f7 in ros::start() () from /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so
#6  0xb7e2c317 in ros::NodeHandle::construct(std::string const&, bool) () from /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so
#7  0xb7e2d7a3 in ros::NodeHandle::NodeHandle(std::string const&, std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > > const&) ()
   from /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so
#8  0xb7e6f434 in ros::AsyncSpinnerImpl::AsyncSpinnerImpl(unsigned int, ros::CallbackQueue*) () from /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so
#9  0xb7e71d94 in ros::AsyncSpinner::AsyncSpinner(unsigned int) () from /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so
#10 0x080a22f9 in main ()
```

EDIT 2:
More info on the boost linking:

```
$ ldd vicon_bridge  | grep boost
libboost_signals.so.1.46.1 => /usr/lib/libboost_signals.so.1.46.1 (0xb70ba000)
libboost_system.so.1.46.1 => /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.46.1 (0xb7090000)
libboost_thread.so.1.46.1 => /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1 (0xb7079000)
libboost_filesystem.so.1.46.1 => /usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.46.1 (0xb7034000)
libboost_regex.so.1.46.1 => /usr/lib/libboost_regex.so.1.46.1 (0xb6d8e000)
```

I get the same output even after I run commands like:

```
$ catkin_make --force-cmake --pkg vicon_bridge -DBoost_DIR=/home/cohrint/catkin_ws/src/vicon_bridge/vicon_sdk/Vicon_SDK_1.3_Linux/32-bit/ -DBoost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS=ON -DBoost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS="1.53;1.53.0"
```

and I get the same thing whenever I try to edit the CMakeLists.txt file as specified [in this post](http://answers.ros.org/question/71428/including-boost-154/?answer=71776#post-id-71776).

EDIT3: I've now reinstalled everything on a 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 install, and I still get issues with Boost. Here's the output of `roslaunch vicon_bridge vicon.launch`:

```
process[vicon-1]: started with pid [2993]
[ INFO] [1409066865.764183805]: Connecting to Vicon DataStream SDK at 192.168.20.10:801 ...
[ INFO] [1409066865.766696029]: .
[ INFO] [1409066866.767665040]: ... connected!
[ INFO] [1409066866.767822995]: Setting Stream Mode to ClientPull: Success
[ INFO] [1409066866.767871496]: Axis Mapping: X-Forward Y-Left Z-Up
[ INFO] [1409066866.767906874]: Version: 1.3.0
[ INFO] [1409066866.767946398]: setting up grab_vicon_pose service server ... 
[ INFO] [1409066866.769546522]: setting up segment calibration service server ... 
[ WARN] [1409066866.772330340]: grab frame returned false
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::thread_interrupted'
```

and to show which libraries it's using by running `ldd vicon_bridge | grep boost`:

```
libboost_thread.so.1.46.1 => /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1 (0x00007f9956a21000)
libboost_thread-mt.so.1.53.0 => /home/cohrint/catkin_ws/src/vicon_bridge/vicon_sdk/Vicon_SDK_1.3_Linux/64-bit/libboost_thread-mt.so.1.53.0 (0x00007f9955a18000)
libboost_system-mt.so.1.53.0 => /home/cohrint/catkin_ws/src/vicon_bridge/vicon_sdk/Vicon_SDK_1.3_Linux/64-bit/libboost_system-mt.so.1.53.0 (0x00007f9955815000)
libboost_signals.so.1.46.1 => /usr/lib/libboost_signals.so.1.46.1 (0x00007f995534f000)
libboost_system.so.1.46.1 => /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.46.1 (0x00007f9954f22000)
libboost_filesystem.so.1.46.1 => /usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.46.1 (0x00007f99548dd000)
libboost_regex.so.1.46.1 => /usr/lib/libboost_regex.so.1.46.1 (0x00007f9953de7000)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190902/two-versions-of-libboost?/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2014-08-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2014-08-21**:
Are those dependencies on 1.53 header-only?

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2014-08-21**:
I actually don't know how to check that. I assumed the dependencies were on libboost1.53 because of [these libraries in the package](https://github.com/ethz-asl/vicon_bridge/tree/master/vicon_sdk/Vicon_SDK_1.3_Linux/32-bit)

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2014-08-21**:
It looks like the 1.53 libs are wrapped inside the package, so it shouldn't conflict with your Boost libs system-wide.

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2014-08-21**:
So the segfault is unrelated to boost? Why would AsyncSpinner() cause a segfault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if this is fixable the easy way. To me, it looks like the problem is boost thread, which appears to be not header only. I'm not too much into linking, so here is my naive interpretation of the problem:
The boost thread header compiled in the vicon-lib is compatible to the thread symbol for 1.5x , while ros asks for 1.4x . Since both symbols have the same name, there is  no chance for the linker to decide which lib is the correct one to link... Back then, I played quite a bit with linking, the result was always the same: either the vicon sdk segfaulted or our ros interface, depending on which boost lib the linker decided to link.

The only (but ugly) way out I see for now, is to install a matching boost version and compile ros from source. We did this on a few of our machines successfully, since we ran into other problems with the old boost version.

Even though the linking problem still exists, it didn't crash on our 64 bit machines so far.

---

Originally posted by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) with karma: 390 on 2014-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2014-08-25**:
Well, I'm running this all in a VM (Nootrix's [ROS Hydro](http://nootrix.com/2014/04/virtualized-ros-hydro/)), so I can always make my own 64-bit VM, though I'll have to reconfigure a fair bit. Here's hoping it'll work!

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2014-08-26**:
See edit above. Tried it with a new 64-bit linux, but still Boost issues arise.  Seems like it's mixing libboost and libboost-mt, somehow.

**Comment by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) on 2014-08-26**:
Do you mean edit 3? It looks like it doesn't even connect to the vicon computer. the segfault usually happened after it connected successfully. Can you ping the vicon computer with "ping vicon" ? you can change the hostname/address in vicon.launch

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2014-08-26**:
You might have to click 'more' to be able to see the rest - my initial post is starting to get pretty long!

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2014-08-26**:
I checked it with the `testclient` binary, and everything looks fine - I'm getting a steady stream of data from the Vicon SDK. Here's [a file containing the output of `gdb`](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/372239/vicon-crash.txt).

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2014-08-27**:
So, it looks like the segfaults don't always happen. My tactic now is to simply run the roslaunch over and over until it works, and then just stick with that. Not an elegant solution in the slightest (and I'll post more if I can figure it out!) but it's technically working! Thanks for all the help!

**Comment by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) on 2014-08-28**:
sorry for missing the "more" button ;) . This is quite weird, I was sure we had it running on 64-bit 12.04 machines. There is one last thing you could try to do: remove the boost libs from the sdk directory, and try to link your system's boost_system the catkin way.